# Problem with glibc version while crosscompiling

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, glibc

I tried crosscompiling a programm in Ubuntu for a Raspberry pi CM3 board. I finally got the compiler to work but whenever i try to run the output on the rPi I only get the error: '/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./programm)'
I found out, that the rPi only has GLIBC 2.24 (it uses a modified version of the Linux kernel, cant change the OS because this is an embedded microcontroller) and that there is no newer version of GLIBC availabe that is not experimental (can't use the experimental version because it needs to run stable).

I tried manually updating GLIBC but to no success.
I looked up linking to a static GLIBC version but all the posts i found recommended not to do it.

Comment: They don't recommend linking a static GLIBC because it may make the system un-bootable. Have you considered building your program against an older version of GLIBC that is compatible with the Raspberry Pi CM3 board? Another way to try is by updating the system by usual `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. You might to upgrade your `libc6` package.

Comment: i already tried updating the system but there is no update for this modified version of linux. i will give building against an older version a try, thx for the advice